# Why SessionDestroyedEvent fires twice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, logout

I have the following  session destroying listener:

```
public class SessionStateListener implements ApplicationListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionStateListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {            
        if (event instanceof SessionDestroyedEvent) {               
            System.out.println("log out");            
        }
    }
}
```

I have logged in as user1, then I open another browser as login a user1 one more time.

After it I see that `"log out"` outputs twice.
For me expecte result - 1.

Can you explain this behaviour?

### P.S.

spring security configuration:

```
<bean id="concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy" class="com.MyConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="mySessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</bean>
```

### P.P.S

this event fires even if I log in by first user first time

Comment: Hmm, what to you mean by *another browser*? If it is really a different browser (say firefox for 1 and chrome for 2), then you open 2 different sessions, and at the end close 2 sessions, even if they concern same user.

Comment: Two independent browsers will open two independent sessions. Because one browser knows nothing about sessions already opened in another one.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta note my P.S. section

Comment: @ Ken Bekov see my P.S. section. I forbid it using spring security

Comment: So you have implemented a custom concurrent session control strategy. What strategy have you implemented? Close previous session? Close new? Close both?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta **Close previous session** - this point

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Spring works based on servlets. Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) creates instance of session ([StandardSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.html)) by default. This instance of session is not related to Spring security.

During first login Spring security destroys this default session, and creates it's own session instance, associated with certain user.

But for `HttpSessionEventPublisher` (who actually notifies `ApplicationListener`) it doesn't matter, is this instance of session related to Spring security or not. It just listening for events that occurring with session, and notifies others.

That is why this event fires twice. When you login first time, Spring destroying default container's session. When you login second time, your session-strategy class destroying user's previous session.